# Adding new file to SVN repository using JAVA

Tags: java, svn

I have to create a application which add new file to SVN repository and commit it.
I have tried the method `doImport` but it create new path in svn.
But according to my need I have to put a new file in the existing SVN path.

I am using `SVNkit-1.8.8`.

```
    try {
        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager("user", "password");
        SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();
        clientManager.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
        SVNURL url;
        url = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded("svn://scm/branches/Test/");
        clientManager.createRepository(url, false);

        File defaultConfigDir = new File("C:\\Test\\text.txt");
        ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(defaultConfigDir, true);

        File f = new File("C:\\Test\\text.txt");
       // File[] fileList = new File[]{f};
        SVNCommitClient scc = new SVNCommitClient(authManager,options);

        scc.doImport(f, 
                     url, 
                     "Commit Successful", 
                     null, 
                     false, 
                     false, 
                     SVNDepth.INFINITY );
    }catch (SVNException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Above code I am trying.

Please help !! 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is not very specific. You should provide some source code; otherwise it is really hard to tell you anything else but to check out the documentation, for example http://svnkit.com/documentation.html

Comment: @EddyG I have checked some of the documents...let me edit my question little bit...

Comment: @EddyG let me know if you need any more info

Comment: I have to admit: your code looks reasonable. Maybe this helps: http://subversion.1072662.n5.nabble.com/How-to-upload-a-file-td912.html

Comment: @EddyG but it shows `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E150002: Path 'svn://scm//branches/Test' already exists`

Comment: I guess that means: digging into the API and play with it. I dont have the means here to recreate your problem. That is what makes programming so interesting: sometimes you have to simply dig into a problem until you find the solution. 
The only other idea I have: check if you can find specific support for SVNKit; there might be mailing lists, IRC channels or other places where you can get into contact with people that are using this product every day.